# When do i need to use echo with strings in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've noticed that my php inside of a WordPress site work without actually echoing some strings in specific situations.

**Example:**

`<a href="<?php echo esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>">link</a>`

`<a href="<?php esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>">link</a>`

Both code output the permalink on my wordpress website. (Versions: PHP 7.17, WP 4.9.8)

**Question:**
When do I need to use echo and which security concerns do I need to be aware of?

Comment: `echo` will print the value. Use when you want to display the data to the user.

Comment: You echo whenever you need to display variables `the_permalink()` already does echo. If you would do `get_the_permalink()` it will show in the first example but not in the second..

Comment: ahh, so i dont need to echo when it is in a href="" for an example. But if i want it to be shown directly on the page i would have to echo it, yeah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why both output the URL is because you are using [the_permalink()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) - which **echos** the permalink.  That in turn means it is NOT getting run through your `esc_url` -

Instead, you need to use `echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() );` - where [get_the_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/) does *not* echo, but returns - therefore it *will* get passed into `esc_url`, which will then require the `echo`

*The only difference* between `the_permalink` and `get_the_permalink`: one echo's, one returns.

Note that WordPress is full of handy functions that work this same way:

[the_ID()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_id) vs [get_the_ID()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id),
[the_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title) vs [get_the_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title),
etc...

Special case:
[the_content()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content) vs [get_the_content()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content)
Be aware however that `the_content`, while naming follows the same pattern and does echo vs. return, `the_content` has an additional difference that it passes the content through the `the_content` filters (which does a lot of formatting, expands shortcodes, etc).

Comment: So in short, wordpress has build in functions that already echos it?

Comment: Depending on which function you use, correct.  That is _the only difference_ between `the_permalink` and `get_the_permalink`: one echo's, one returns.

Comment: @cale-b your advice needs clarifying a little as `get_the_content()` is _not_ the same as `the_content()` in that the post content data is returned raw, whereas `the_content()` also passes the data through the 'the_content' filter to process shortcodes, oembeds, etc.

Comment: @PeterHvD - fair enough, I will indeed clarify - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/) the function the_permalink() Displays the permalink for the current post.
So it has built-in functionality to print output without echo so you can use whatever text you like as the link text, in this case, “permalink”.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">permalink</a>
```

**Echo**

The echo() function outputs one or more strings.

> echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you
>   are not required to use parentheses with it. echo (unlike some other
>   language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot
>   always be used in the context of a function. Additionally, if you want
>   to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters must not be
>   enclosed within parentheses.

Comment: Does it matter which function i use in a <a title="<?php the_title ?>"></a>, should i rather use get_the_title?

Comment: https://pippinsplugins.com/use-the_title-and-the_title_attribute-correctly/ according to this website its less secure to use both. I found out that I actually need to use the_title_attribute instead.